# how to remove dependency on integration account when performing debatching/decoding

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Logic-apps allow you to do lots of EDI / file-processing operations, such as flat-file decoding:

[image: https://photos.google.com/lr/photo/AHOXsYIs1l31oeyuel9l-jj1kkMmYcvUnFRDy839XjrvbvHgNg8RnVVitYq1One2OI0JYaxrGnJHm3aibCkwa1dxCzrjSst_JA]

The `FromApexDemoEntry` is a schema that is hosted in the [integration account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account).

**Is it possible to perform these operations without having an integration account?**

For example, could we simply have an Azure Function that will accept a message along with with a schema and perform the flat file decoding step without having to go to an integration account?

Answer (score 6):

For EDI specifically, you must have an Integration Account because that is where all of the EDI configuration exists.  There is no *practical* way around this.

Keep in mind, EDI is different from 'flat files'.  Native flat file processing also required an Integration Account because of the schemas.

While you theoretically could parse a flat file in a Function and Loop over the result in a Logic App...you really don't want to.  It would be **a lot of custom parsing code** to duplicate something that's already built into Logic Apps.

You will almost certainly **spend more money developing a custom solution** than just paying for the Integration Account.

Comment: what are your thoughts on this bypassing integration account https://devkimchi.com/2019/01/07/building-xsl-mapper-with-azure-functions/

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' That example is for transforms only which could be a serviceable solution using Functions for that specific case.  Parsing, EDI or Flat File, are completely different scenarios.

Comment: how would flat file be different? that would also be a function that accepts a payload and returns the decoded flat file

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Because Transform is *very* different from Parsing.  You can transform with xsl/Liquid.  Parsing is all custom code.

Comment: when you say _parsing is all custom code_ what do you mean by parsing? do you mean in regards to debatching individual records inside of a CSV?